# Prevent android app reverse engineering on Airwatch managed devices

Tags: android, mdm, android-security, airwatch

From the Airwatch features and documentation, they mention that the apps are containerized. And thus, all the app content is safely encrypted and not easily exposed.

For rooted devices, Airwatch can detect such devices and perform a remote wipe of corporate data.

I wanted to check if Airwatch can guarantee that the application code cannot be reverse-engineered, to extract sensitive data from the code base, like API keys, Encryption keys etc.

Comment: Good to see you Kumar after been long time. To others, sorry for off-topic comment but yeah Stackoverflow is a platform for developers networking and discussion!

Comment: There's no such thing as 100% guaranteed safety!, A skilled programmer can reverse engineer.. You can still use proguard to obfuscate your code but again, No such thing as 100% safety.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to check if Airwatch can guarantee that the application code cannot be reverse-engineered, to extract sensitive data from the code base, like API keys, Encryption keys etc.

While I cannot advise you in relation to Airwatch, because I am not familiar with it, I can alert you that if you are storing this type of sensitive information in your mobile app, then you are already at risk, because reverse engineering secrets are not that hard as I show in the article [How to Extract an API key from a Mobile App by Static Binary analysis](https://blog.approov.io/how-to-extract-an-api-key-from-a-mobile-app-with-static-binary-analysis):

> Summary
>
> Using MobSF to reverse engineer an APK for a mobile app allows us to quickly extract an API key and also gives us a huge amount of information we can use to perform further analysis that may reveal more attack vectors into the mobile app and API server. It is not uncommon to also find secrets for accessing third part services among this info or in the decompiled source code that is available to download in smali and java formats.
>
> Now you may be questioning yourself as to how you would protect the API key, and for that I recommend starting by reading this series of articles about Mobile Api Security Techniques.
>
> The lesson here is that shipping your API key or any other secret in the mobile app code is like locking the door of your home but leaving the key under the mat!

or even with a MitM attack in this [other article](https://blog.approov.io/steal-that-api-key-with-a-man-in-the-middle-attack):

> Conclusion
>
> While we can use advanced techniques, like JNI/NDK, to hide the API key in the mobile app code, it will not impede someone from performing a MitM attack in order to steal the API key. In fact a MitM attack is easy to the point that it can even be achieved by non developers.
>
> We have highlighted some good resources that will show you other techniques to secure mobile APIs, like certificate pinning, even though it can be challenging to implement and to maintain. We also noted that certificate pinning by itself is not enough since it can be bypassed, thus other techniques need to be employed to guarantee that no one can steal your API key, and, if you have completed the deep dive I recommended, you will know by now that in the context of a mobile API, the API key can be protected from being stolen through a MitM attack. So if you have not already done it, please read the articles I linked to in the section about mitigating MitM attacks.

Also more skilled developers can hook, at run-time, some introspection frameworks, like Frida and xPosed, to intercept and modify behavior of any of your running code. So even if they are not able to decrypt your data, they will intercept the content after you have decrypted it in your application. To be able to do this, they just need to know were to hook into your code, and this they achieve by de-compiling and reverse engineer the code of your mobile app with the help of tools, like the Mobile Security Framework or APKTool, but more tools exist in the open source community.

[Mobile Security Framework](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF)

> Mobile Security Framework is an automated, all-in-one mobile application (Android/iOS/Windows) pen-testing framework capable of performing static analysis, dynamic analysis, malware analysis and web API testing.

[Frida](https://www.frida.re/)

> Inject your own scripts into black box processes. Hook any function, spy on crypto APIs or trace private application code, no source code needed. Edit, hit save, and instantly see the results. All without compilation steps or program restarts.

[xPosed](https://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)

> Xposed is a framework for modules that can change the behavior of the system and apps without touching any APKs. That's great because it means that modules can work for different versions and even ROMs without any changes (as long as the original code was not changed too much). It's also easy to undo.

[APKTool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/)

> A tool for reverse engineering 3rd party, closed, binary Android apps. It can decode resources to nearly original form and rebuild them after making some modifications. It also makes working with an app easier because of the project like file structure and automation of some repetitive tasks like building apk, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but wanted to know specific to AirWatch.

Comment: If they encrypt the binary they will need to decrypt it for the App to be able to run, thus the keys will be on the device and up for grabs by skilled attackers, with tools like Frida or xPosed. So in the end of the day you can make it harder but not impossible. So my advice is to consider any sensitive info or secrets in the App to belong to the public domain.